# beacon frame captured by libpcap is something strange

Tags: c, linux, libpcap, wifi

I captured beacon frame with library libpcap(Ubuntu, c)

I changed wlan mode to monitor and captured by following function calls

```
// 3000 is large enough number for test
pcd = pcap_open_live(dev,3000,PROMISCUOUS,-1,errbuf)  
// filter with "wlan type mgt subtype beacon"    
pcap_compile(pcd,&bpg,"wlan type mgt subtype beacon",1,PCAP_NETMASK_UNKNOWN)
pcap_setfilter(pcd, &bpg)
```

and following is packet_view

```
void packet_view(
    unsigned char *user,
    const struct pcap_pkthdr *h,
    const unsigned char *p
){
    int len;
    len = 0;

    printf("PACKET\n");
    while(len < h->len) {
        printf("%02x ", *(p++));
        if(!(++len % 16))
            printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return ;
}
```

and my got following result (just most significant 32bits)

```
00 00 12 00 2e 48 00 00 00 02 6c 09 a0 00 bb 01 
00 00 80 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 08 9f bf
```

but... actually beacon frame must start with bit "08"
because beacon frame's protocol version = 00 type = 00 and subtype = 1000 => 00001000(08)

what is the reason that i got packet start with 00? althougt I filtered with "wlan type mgt subtype beacon" ??

Comment: those "bits" are "bytes"

Comment: ah. right i just mistype but nothing changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing one pcap call - a call to `pcap_datalink()`.

Unless `pcap_datalink()` returns `DLT_IEEE802_11`, the packet does *NOT* begin with an 802.11 header.  If, for example, it returns `DLT_IEEE802_11_RADIO`, the packet begins with a [radiotap header](http://www.radiotap.org), and has an 802.11 header after it; that looks like what your packet has.

See [the tcpdump.org link-layer header types page](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html) for information on the values `pcap_datalink()` can return and the values that appear in pcap and pcap-ng files.

Comment: thanks a lot, pcap_datalink() returns IEEE802_11_RADIO and after 18bytes from start i finally find my beacon frame!

Comment: Don't hardwire 18 into your program; instead, if the link-layer type is `DLT_IEEE802_11_RADIO`, then fetch the length from the radiotap header (note that it's little-endian, not big-endian!) and skip over that many bytes.  Radiotap headers are not guaranteed to have any particular fixed length.

Comment: I was using two different adapters to sniff beacon frames using my own pcap code in C. One of the adapters, D-LINK, is unable of "true" monitor mode but it can, through some effort with custom linux driver hear the beacon frames :). Now the other, TP-LINK WN722N, can be put to monitor mode, but I didn't manage to sniff the beacon frames using my own code (I could only see the beacons through wireshark). But your little comment on "little-endian...big endian" saved the day! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Set your filter to
"link[0] == 0x80"
Works for me!

Since apparently 
https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters

Capture WLAN traffic without Beacons:
link[0] != 0x80